# how to find and fix the cause of the crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, asihttprequest, xcode-instruments

I submited an app to the app store and it was rejected due to:

> "We found that your app crashed on iPhone 5 running iOS 6.1.2, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>
> Your app crashed when we:
>
> when the user taps to sign into the app, a crash is produced.
>
> This occurred when your app was used:
>
> - On Wi-Fi
> - On cellular network
>
> Your app may encounter this issue if it is using too much memory. To learn more about iOS memory usage and how to track memory usage and leaks, please see the Memory Usage Performance Guidelines."

I couldn't trigger the crash again on my side. I profiled my app with the allocations instrument, and saw that that my live bytes never exceeded 12MB. With the leaks instrument I figured out that I have a few leaks (all in 3rd party sources), but they are very minor and shouldn't have cause the app to crash.. I have no clue what to do..

1. Did the app really crash due to using too much memory?
2. Could there be another reason?
3. How should I approach this and fix the problem?

EDIT - attached the [crash log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fnuanp4qz2n2x0i/symbolicated%20crash%20log.rtf)

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099211/ad-hoc-builds-crashing-on-device-only-asihttprequest)&[that](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/issues/341), it seems like using ASIHTTPRequest framework is causing the crash some how, but only on ad-hoc or distribution builds, which makes debugging it more of a headache. **Is it really the cause? Should I switch to AFNetworking instead?**

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14825056/581994

Comment: Without more data, especially the crash report, answers would be hypothetical. Please follow the advice in the linked page for this and future questions: http://emclstcd.tk/

Comment: I symbolicated the crash log and attached a link to it in the question. @HotLicks, I checked out the duplicate and it helped me symbolicate the crash log, however - I couldn't find there an answer to the 1,2,3 questions I mentioned..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should switch to AFNetworking, because ASIHTTPRequest is not supported any more.

To debug this issue, try to set *Optimization Level* to *Fastest, Smalles [-Os]*. This is usually the reason, why debug and release code behaves differently.

Comment: Setting Optimization Level to Fastest, Smalles [-Os] helped me trigger the crash on my side. The bug was in the ASIHTTPRequest package. I switched to using AFNetworking instead and everything was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Did the app really crash due to using too much memory?

No your app crashed because of a bad access. Normally this means you tried to access a deallocated object.

How should I approach this and fix the problem?

The crash occurs in line 132 of your Server.m (Method: registerWithUserProvider:). You should have a look at this method. Maybe a simple nil check can solve your problem but thats hard to say without code.