# Implementing OAuth 1.0 in an iOS app (Withings api)

Tags: ios, oauth, withings

I'm developing an iOS app with Withings api.
I've been trying to implement OAuth 1.0 in an iOS app but I couldn't.
I saw [Implementing OAuth 1.0 in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930628/implementing-oauth-1-0-in-an-ios-app) page.
And at the second answer he suggested TDOAuth https://github.com/tweetdeck/TDOAuth.
I tried the code and got many errors.
If anyone has code examples or projects, please share through this page.

Answer (score 2):

You can use oauth.io as they have now implemented Withings OAuth and they have an iOS SDK https://github.com/oauth-io/oauth-ios

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/oauthconsumer/wiki/UsingOAuthConsumer

try that link all the steps are clearly explained, it is explained in general, if you want to connect to a specific website's service, add the required parameters for that site to the OARequest using OARequestParameter class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the blog I have written after successfully integrating Withings using simple-OAuth1,don't know whether it will be helpful or not..http://integratingwithings.blogspot.in/2014/05/withings-api-declassified-ios.html

Comment: I've been trying to implement yours and I have been having a few issues.  Do you have the source code available so I can compare it to my project and figure out where I went wrong?

Comment: yes, You can have the source code,please see the blog comment reply for that.