# How to call OAuth 1.0 api in NSMutableURLRequest objective C?

Tags: objective-c, oauth, nsmutableurlrequest

I want to call oAuth 1.0 api using NSMutableURLRequest. I passed all value in header. But it gives authorisation header failed.
Let me know how to pass OAuth value in header.
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15930628/implementing-oauth-1-0-in-an-ios-app ?

Comment: @Larme All answer in this question is given based on TDOAuth library, now it is old and has too many errors. I want NSMutableURLRequest authorisation header request.